# Creating comments that belong to their respective microposts and users (in an app using Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have two models: User and Micropost.
The User model is working with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

*Example of the files involved:*

**user_controller.html.erb:**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @microposts = @user.microposts
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb:**

```
<h2>Pages index</h2>
<p>email <%= @user.email %></p>
<p>microposts <%= render @microposts %></p>
```

**microposts/_micropost.html.erb**

```
<p><%= micropost.content %></p>
```

**micropost.rb:**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rg:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :microposts
end
```

Now I want to create comments for the microposts:

- Each comment should belong to its respective micropost and user (commenter). Not sure how to do this (is it a good situation to use **polymorphic associations**?).
- An user should have many microposts and comments (not sure how to co this either).
- I have no idea how to make it so that the comment is made the the user who is currently    signed in (I think I have to do something with Devise's `current_user`).

Any suggestions to accomplish this? (Sorry, I'm a Rails beginner)

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing you've said suggests that you need polymorphic associations.  What you need is a comments model with a schema something like the following:

```
    create_table :comments do |t|
        t.text :comment, :null => false
        t.references :microposts
        t.references :user
        t.timestamps
    end
```

And then

```
# user.rb
has_many :microposts
has_many :comments

# microposts.rb
has_many :comments
```

You will probably want nested routes for your comments.  So, in your routes.rb you'll have something like

```
#routes.rb
resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
end
```

.. and in your comments controller, yes, you'll assign the value of comment.user something like the following...

```
# comments_controller.rb
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save ....
end
```

You might want to look at the Beginning Rails 3 book, which would walk you through this.